# El Capitan pear command not found

Tags: macos, pear

I am new to mac and am trying to get pear to run from the terminal.
All the scripts are added to the MAMP folder and if I run:

```
$ sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/bin/pear
```

everything is fine.

However, if I run $sudo pear or pear I get a message: "pear command not found"

My $PATH variable looks like this:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/bin/pear:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:
```

When I look for pear with $ locate bin/pear I get the same location as in the path:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/bin/pear
```

Any idea what can be wrong?

Comment: I suspect your $PATH needs to point to the directory rather than the executable.  (`/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/bin`)

Comment: That was it, thank you. You can write an answer so that we can close the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copied -- in essence -- from a comment:

Th $PATH environment variable should contain a list of directories to be searched for a command.  Having the executable itself as part of the path doesn't help with resolving its location.